# Identifying a seed

Tags: seeds

I bought a selection box of cooking spices in Sri Lanka and it has Diusseeds in it. Please see the picture below.
Could anyone help me identify what these are and how to use them?
Many thanks
[image]

Comment: What size are they? To match the fenugreek I've got, the print must be very small

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [fenugreek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenugreek) to me, though it's darker than I'm used to seeing.
The leaves are sometimes called methi, but I don't know if that extends to the seeds too. Googling 'diusseed' gives very few results, mostly images that also look just like fenugreek.

It should have quite a distinctive smell - Wikipedia calls it a 'maple syrup' smell, but I can't comment on that as I've never smelled maple syrup ;)